# Where to set value of liveServer.settings.port in live server extension of visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, port-number, liveservertestcase

I am working on Angular7 with visual studio code editor 
URL: http://localhost:4200 (Working fine)

But, I installed extension **Live Server** and when I click on Liveserver icon its giving me the error

> "Error on port 5500. Please try to change the port through settings or
>   report on GitHub."

So, I opened the **File->preference->Settings->LiveServerConfig** and 
tried to change port in settings.json file

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib",
    "tslint.enable": false,
    "liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "QiwkCollaboratorTool",
    "liveServer.settings.root": 0  // New added line
}
```

Am I going into right direction or am I missing something ? I am not sure how to change the port number 5500 to 0 as I want random port number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you need to serve on port 80, you need to run this... netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got the answer I was editing the wrong settings.json there were two .json files.

[image]

Also, I put the below code:

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "",
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0
}
```

But thanks Danny

Answer (score 10):

I hope this helps:
in the settings.json add the following line.

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 0,
```

A value 0 (zero) is used for a random port. Any other numbers is for a fixed port number.

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Comment: @FZs thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

**1.** First, navigate to `Settings` *(Ctrl+Comma)*.

[image: First]

**2.** Now click on `Extensions`, which is located on the left side of the window.

[image: Screenshot]

**3.** After that, scroll down and find a tab by the name of `Live Server Config`.

**4.** Click on that, scroll down, now click on `Edit in settings.json` under `Settings: Port`.

[image: Screenshot]

**5.** A new window will pop up. Here you go, now you can change the port number.

[image: Screenshot]

**6.** At the end, save the file `Ctrl+s`.

> liveServer.settings.port: Customize Port Number of your Live Server.
> If you want random port number, set it as 0.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
I also need to set the custom port number to my application in locally tried above and this is how it is configured now.