# Vs code live server extension is not updating my page automatically. New content only displays when i relaunch it with(open live server)

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

Even though my default browser is set to chrome in json setting file. But still live server is not pushing the changes of my page to browser. Every time, i have to relaunch the browser from vs code.

I have checked the following

1. In Json file the default browser is set to chrome
2. reinstalled both the live server and vs code but in vain

Answer (score 0):

May be you setting json file not correct. You can try as steps below (for Windows):

1. Change **Setting Https:** to "false"
2. Setting **Auto Save** to "after Delay" and modify number of **Auto Save Delay**
3. 1.Close the vs code -> 2.Go to the properties of My Pc ->3.Click on Advanced Settings ->4.click on Environmental Variables ->5.from there you can add path clicking the path variables in the table shown there 6 . Add a new line to the path as picture -> open again and enjoy!
   --
   [image]