# A new strange message in the console of Chrome when using live server extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since a while I found two new strange messages in the console of Chrome, particularly when initiating the live server extension. The two messages are:

```
onMessage extension
Clean the cache of the scraper (new onComplete event)
```

What are the causes of these two strange annoying messages? and how can I get rid of them both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163221/ritwick-deys-live-server-extension-in-visual-studio-code-not-opening-website-in

Comment: This is far from the purpose of the question.

Comment: I am seeing the same message and only on one computer. Is it possibly a spy type screen scraper on that browser?