# Errors in React with @tailwind and @apply, tried all the obvious

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

No matter what I do I cannot fix the errors: Unknown at rule @tailwind css(unkownAtRules)
and: Unknown at rule @apply

I am using React, I've installed everything necessary and tried all the suggestions from AI tools like copilot. All my config files look good.

I tried clearing the cache, double checking everything was installed correctly and config files were right. No change to the errors.

Comment: Are these error in the browser?

Comment: Sounds like your IDE is preventing you from using it as intended. Sometimes you need to edit a configuration option in VS Code for example to ignore ruling on custom @ rules like @tailwind.

For context, [this is what I'm talking about](https://byby.dev/at-rule-tailwind#:~:text=There%20are%20several%20ways%20to,this%20by%20opening%20the%20settings)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like your IDE/Code editor isn't allowing the custom @ directives that Tailwind uses.

For example, in VS Code you will need to open your `settings.json` file and add this rule:

```
{
  "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

Or, if you're using something like SCSS:

```
{
  "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction. Remember to restart your editor once you've made changes.

Comment: That worked in the workspace settings.json file. Thank you! Now I'm getting a spelling error on this line in the settings.json user file even though i didnt change it: "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,

Comment: It says donot is an unknown word. Also getting an error with a font, satoshi, which is coming up as an unkown word.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but maybe check the info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698795/live-server-problem-with-settings-json-being-for-a-different-extension - I only really know the answer to your original question, which is what my answer solved